# Function that is supposed to return a value from query

Tags: php, sql

I have this function which I use to get a value from a query. I might be doing something wrong with the execution, or the syntax. When I try to run the query with the data in it, it's fine, but this one returns 0 items.

```
public function get_modified_event ($type, $id, $employee_id)
        {
            global $dbh;
            $sql =<<<SQL

                    SELECT outlook_id 
                        FROM dba.events
                    WHERE spine_item_type = :type
                    AND spine_id = :id
                    AND employee_id = :employee_id 
SQL;

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->execute( array(
                    'id' => $id,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'employee_id' => $employee_id,

            ) );
                    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
                    return $rows['outlook_id'];
        }
```

Comment: first, do not use `global`. It sucks. I assume you do not do unit testing, but still, do not use `global`. It sucks. Other than that - maybe it returns because there's no record to match your criteria. Display query, execyte it by hand and see

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I already tried to execute it by hand and I get a value

Comment: @TMA where does $spine_type come from?

Comment: `print_r($rows);`? Also `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as very first line in that script.

Comment: @chris85 yep that's right, sorry, it's not updated, but that's not the problem

Comment: You should update the question in that case.

Comment: @chris85 done! I try   $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['outlook_id']; and I get false..

Comment: `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );`

Comment: @mwweb, nope, nothing changes :/

Comment: `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT outlook_id  FROM dba.events WHERE spine_item_type = :type AND spine_id = :id AND employee_id = :employee_id");`

Comment: @mwweb thanks for trying, but I get the same result, an array of 0

Comment: @TMA what is the slash mark doing here: $stmt->fetchAll( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

Comment: ok try to print `var_dump($rows);` ??

Comment: @TMA: correction -- what you designate as a function is actually a method that is part of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reworking a portion of the code so that it uses this kind of a format:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
if ($stmt->execute( /* your array goes here */ )) {
       $rows = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
       if ($rows !== FALSE){
                  print_r($rows);
        }
        else 
        if ( $stmt->rowCount() === 0) {
           echo "The info provided is unknown to the database";
        }
 }
```

Hopefully you'll get some meaningful results.

Comment: Thank you! Hmm now it fails in the execution part... Is there any other way to rewrite this query that you can help me with?